# Insert a separator in between elements of different width

Tags: javascript, carousel

I am trying to develop a JavaScript carousel, which has the following features:

- Circular
- Carousel movement starts with mouse hover on prev/next buttons
- Availability of setting visual separator between last and first elements of the carousel

I found this http://www.enova-tech.net/eng/lab/jmycarousel and it's perfectly suitable for me. But I can't put a separator between last and first elements of the carousel, because it's width is smaller than width of normal element.

E.g.

```
<li width=200></li>
<li width=200></li>
<li width=200></li>
<li width=50>separator</li>
```

And this carousel believes that every element has the same width (I guess not only this carousel, but many others too), so because of that I am not able to get my carousel working. How do I insert a separator between the first and the last elements?

I tried using jCarousel, but it has a similar problem.